# how to use well html5 tags into a specific service web site

Tags: html, tags

I've read some html5 doc and how to use tags, expecially news
I have a site www.webmaster-toolbox.com and is like an utility, it prints some informations about a site.

well I have separate in 2 section

results_sect: where I put all results
analize_sect: where I put search bar

well about header and article I have no idea like use them in my situation, so the question is but html5 is only useful for blog? no for this kinda sites? thanks

if not can help me microformats to better indicize page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 5 is useful not only for blogs. **It is extremely helpful to create a very meaningful semantic HTML which not only the browser could understand even the human could understand clearly.**

Previously to create header part of the document we pretty much use div with the id/class as header. Now with the help of HTML5 we could use the header tag to semantically structure the document.

You could use article tag can be used for blog post or forum post etc...You could also use section tag to seperate different content meaningfully rather going with the traditional div approach.

Comment: Yes you could go ahead using the section tag to segregate the meaningful content in HTML instead of Div.

_if this answer helps you please try to accept the answer and +1 it_